# strange behaviour when printing a float and then an Array

Tags: c

I try to print out two arrays with the following function using XCode 6.1.1:

```
for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
    for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        printf("%2d ", Lattice[0][j+N*k]);
    }
    printf("        ");
    for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        printf("%2d ", Lattice[1][j+N*k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

Everything works fine when calling the function, 
as long as I don't print out a float before.
When printing an int, there's no problem. So it's a
little strange, right?
I'm initializing the array like this:

```
int **Lattice =  (int**)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
if (Lattice == NULL) return NULL;

for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    Lattice[i] =  (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    if (Lattice[i] == NULL) {
        for (int n=0; n<i; n++)
            free(Lattice[n]);
        free(Lattice);
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k<M; k++) {
                Lattice[i][j+N*k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
return Lattice;
```

Too bad, I can't upload an image of the output.

The matrices should show only zeros, but with the float 
there will be big numbers in some entries which i can't explain.

I'm grateful for any hints.
Thank you.

Comment: Funny, no `float` variables or constants appear **anywhere** in your code!!!

Comment: What's the value of N and M, for you only allocated space for 2 `int`

Comment: `Lattice[i] =  (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));`: you REALLY want to allocate only 2 ints per line? Not N*M, as suggested by the second double loop? Btw, to initialize an array to 0, you can use `memset`, or even `calloc` in place of `malloc`.

Comment: Lattice is a pointer to pointers to integers.  Dereferencing this as a 2D array (`Lattice[x][y]`) will not work because the compiler expects the rows to be contiguous, rather than an additional level of re-direction.  You could either use a single level of malloc to allocate a contiguous 2D array, or dereference it indirectly (e.g. `(Lattice[x])[y]`).

Comment: Thank you Bentoy13. You got it. Right this second I found the mistake myself. Stupid me. Still it's strange that to print a float or an int makes the difference.

Comment: Your `malloc`'s are wrong, you are only allocating an array of 2, 2 `int`'s arrays.

Answer (score 1):

So your code has some pretty serious problems.

`Lattice[0]` and `Lattice[1]` need to have dimensions 4x4 for your printing block of code to make any sense. Incidentally this means `N` and `M` need to equal 4 as well or you need to change your printing `for` loop conditions to `j < N` and `k < M` respectively.

Your `malloc` needs to allocate space for that as well, so: `Lattice[i] =  (int *)malloc(N * M * sizeof(int));`

This should cause your loops to work correctly, but you do not have floats anywhere in your code. You *cannot* use `printf` to print an `int` as a `float`. The value will not be promoted. It will simply be treated as a `float`.